# animate images in the same activity

Tags: android, animation

I want to animate three images one after the other in the same activity.On start of the animation the first image appears for some time,then the second and then the third.I am using frame animation for the same but my problem is that i want the animation everytime i touch the screen.The code will make it clear

```
final AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hammer_one), 200);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hammer_two), 200);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hammer_three), 200);

    animation.setOneShot(true);

    img[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview);
    img[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview1);
    img[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview2);
    img[3] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview3);
    img[4] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview4);
```

These above are the imageviews in my layout.

```
 for(i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){

        img[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    int num = event.getPointerCount();

                     for (int a = 0; a < num; a++) {
                          int x = (int) event.getX(event.getPointerId(a));
                          int y = (int) event.getY(event.getPointerId(a));
                          Log.e("x",x + " ");
                          Log.e("y",y + " ");
                        }

                    arg0.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
                    animation.start();

                    return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    int num = event.getPointerCount();

                     for (int a = 0; a < num; a++) {
                          int x = (int) event.getX(event.getPointerId(a));
                          int y = (int) event.getY(event.getPointerId(a));
                          Log.e("x",x + " ");
                          Log.e("y",y + " ");
                        }

                    arg0.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
                    animation.start();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

The above is the code for onTouch i.e when the layout is touched.
```

Now the above code is working fine as far as the first touch is concerned.But when i touch the layout for the second time only the image appers but the animation does not appears.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be with `animation.setOneShot(true);`? Perhaps, set it to false. Or, in each onTouch event, create a new animation object, rather than reuse the same animation object, on which you've already called `setOneShot(true);`.